# Can a WiFi enabled Arduino make a HTTPS request to my Web Server?

Tags: wifi, web

I need my Arduino to connect to my web server through HTTPS, can the Arduino handle it?

It only has to act as a client.

Comment: Please state which Arduino. There are quite a few different ones.

Comment: I was just checking if it was possible to do some secure cloud connected sensors with the cheap non Linux Arduinos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a better way to do it would be to have a PHP script act as handoff server (maybe protected by originating IP address) to access the HTTPS site and provide the data over a less processor-intensive protocol.

[How to get HTTPS on Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-to-get-https-on-arduino)

However, another answer suggests that we are working towards a solution to your issue, but it's not quite there yet (~12 seconds to encrypt a packet).

https://evothings.com/is-it-possible-to-secure-micro-controllers-used-within-iot/